# PubSub in Scala Redis

Tags: scala, redis

I am new to the Scala and Redis world and I am trying to do something simple:

I want to subscribe to a channel in order to be notified when new keys are added (My idea is just to set the key and publish in a channel that the key was added).

As I was reading in the website, [scala-redis](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis) is the most updated of the recommended versions, so I decided to use it.

I am having some problems with the subscribing part. I have the following code:

```
import com.redis._
val r = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379)
r.subscribe("modifications","modifications","subscribe")
```

I am getting the following error message:

> error: missing arguments for method subscribe in trait PubSub; follow
>   this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied
>   function

I was checking the documentation and the function looks like this:

```
def subscribe(channel: String, channels: String*)(fn: PubSubMessage => Any) {
    if (pubSub == true) { // already pubsub ing
      subscribeRaw(channel, channels: _*)
    } else {
      pubSub = true
      subscribeRaw(channel, channels: _*)
      new Consumer(fn).start
    }
  }
```

To be honest, I don't know what I am doing wrong. If someone could help me with some ideas, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a function to handle the received message:

```
r.subscribe("modifications","modifications","subscribe"){ m => println(m) }
```

Unfortunately most of the documentation is in the code, but it might help if you take a look at the [PubSubDemo](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/c8d2d7d79a413bee733b0c6caee783b80296d595/src/test/scala/com/redis/PubSubServerDemo.scala) or [PubSubSpec](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/c8d2d7d79a413bee733b0c6caee783b80296d595/src/test/scala/com/redis/PubSubSpec.scala).

Comment: The documentation of this api is very poor indeed. Thank you.